# How to run security updates with Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

when I login to a server (Ubuntu 12.04) I'm presented the following message:

```
12 packages can be updated.
10 updates are security updates.
```

Resolving it "by hand" is easy of course (apt-get update && apt-get upgrade), but due to the fact that the server is (partly) provisioned with Chef, I wonder whether there's a good way to include this programmatically into the recipes?

The ["apt" cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt) doesn't seem to provide something related :(

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to automate package updates/upgrades as this can obviously break applications if not properly tested first.

One way to solve this is to have a cookbook lock or hold the repository at a specified version, and then thoroughly test it in development before pushing it out to production.

On Amazon Linux you can retrieve a unique url of the yum repository at it's current state. So you can run an update/upgrade on dev, find out the unique url and push that out to prod. That will prevent Chef from updating to any newer packages than you've tested.

I'm not as familiar with Ubuntu and apt-get, but it looks like you can do what I'm talking about with Pinning or Holding: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

So in summary, you want to upgrade/update a dev machine, you test it, find out what the repo state is and freeze all packages to those versions. Then you freeze prod's repo to those states. Then you just have the cookbook run 'apt-get -y upgrade' as Draco mentioned.

Comment: I agree that it's a bad idea to have updates continuously applied without previous validations. But assuming you already tested updates on your dev environment, how do you propagate those into production? I'm thinking in creating some sort of cookbook which does update/upgrade for all the packages and the repo version is maintained on a data_bag. You can modify the version on the data_bag and next time recipe is executed, it'll run update/upgrade. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I just have `execute 'apt-get -y upgrade'` in my own recipe.

Comment: right, but is that really "common-sense" resp. "best-practice" ?

Comment: But what's wrong with that? It is simple, manageable and does what is needed.

Comment: but it doesn't answer whether this is really best practice - and due to the fact that this is not part of any official cookbook it seems that it isn't ;)

Comment: This is a very bad thing to do.

Comment: @DracoAter Why is it bad to blindly upgrade packages? Because new versions of packages can have breaking changes which will have adverse effects on the services being run on that server.  In general you should only be updating a server if you have to, not because there are updates available, _even_ security updates as these can be mitigated in other ways.

Comment: No, that's taking it a bit too far if you ask me. Only updating if you have to is a recipe for headaches due to reactive management. Updates should be performed on a regular basis and should be incorporated into systems administration as well as development. Chef enables you to dry-run your updates on a shadow-copy of your live environment and test everything you can think of. Embrace this and introduce yourself to weekly update management with rollback scenarios. Use versions in your package definitions to automate this entire process using Chef.

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, I agree that "It's generally a bad idea to automate package updates/upgrades as this can obviously break applications if not properly tested first."  I am sure that is the scholarly answer.

However my experience has been that automatically loading *security updates* will rarely cause a problem, and that should be weighed against the probability of missing or delaying a key security fix.  (We've never allowed automatic reboots, I guess that's where we draw the line.)  The decision whether to do automatic security updates or not should be based on the reality of your situation.  There is not a one-size-fits-all answer.

If you want to run auto updates, there are several cookbooks available (at least for Ubuntu) but unfortunately none seem to be particularly up to date, which is a little ironic.  Here's one example:
[unattended_upgrades](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/unattended_upgrades)

Answer (score 1):

There's an auto-patch cookbook available for this: https://github.com/bflad/chef-auto-patch/.

Also there is a Chef post on how to integrate Chef into your patch process:
https://www.chef.io/solutions/patch-management/

The gist of it is:

- Identify the vulnerability.
- Test the updates.
- Roll out patches.
- Monitor for unexpected side effects.